# No line-break after a hyphen

Tags: html, css, character-encoding, line-breaks, hyphenation

I'm looking to prevent a line break after a hyphen `-` on a case-by-case basis that is compatible with all browsers.

Example:

I have this text:  `3-3/8"` which in HTML is this:  `3-3/8&rdquo;`

The problem is that near the end of a line, because of the hyphen, it breaks and wraps to the next line instead of treating it like a full word...

```
3-
3/8"
```

I've tried inserting the "zero width no break character", `&#65279;` with no luck...

```
3-&#65279;3/8&rdquo;
```

I'm seeing this in Safari and thinking it will be the same in all browsers.

The following is my `doctype` and character encoding...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

Is there any way I can prevent these from line-breaking after the hyphen?  I do not need any solution that applies to the whole page... just something I can insert as needed, like a "zero width no break character", except one that works.

Here is a Demo.  Simply make the frame narrower until the line breaks at the hyphen.

http://jsfiddle.net/RagKH/

Comment: @EricLeschinski, that's already been posted as an answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12362315/594235

Comment: With charset=utf-8 you can put in ‑ a non breaking hyphen

Comment: @QuentinUK, right... isn't that already the accepted answer?  `&#8209;` is a non-breaking hyphen.

Comment: &#8209; is ordinary ASCII, so utf-8 is not necessary. With a utf-8 encoding of the page it is possible to put in the actual characters. ‑ is not the same character as - although it looks the same.

Comment: The correct HTML for what you wrote, would be `3-3/8&Prime;` or `3-3/8&#x2033;`. Quotes are not primes. If you want it in pure ASCII, just use straight double quotes instead (`&#x22;`). Preferably, if it is going to be presented as good, legible text, you would instead use `3<span style="font-variant: diagonal-fractions">3/8</style>&Prime;`, displaying ‘3⅜″’

Comment: This duplicate question [provides a very useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34791403/4575793).

Answer (score 677, accepted):

Try using the non-breaking hyphen `&#8209;`. I've replaced the dash with that character in your jsfiddle, shrunk the frame down as small as it can go, and the line doesn't split there any more.

Comment: I figured it was something like the non-breaking space, so I just searched for 'non-breaking dash', and [ended up here](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~ggbaker/reference/characters/#dash). :-)

Comment: Ahhh... I did a _"no break character"_ search and hit the wall with that `&#65279;`.  It just never occurred to me that there was a stand-alone hyphen character that won't break.

Comment: In IE8/9 this character renders longer than a typical hyphen. It appears to be the same size as an en-dash.

Comment: The reason why the result may differ from a normal hyphen is that many fonts do not contain the non-breaking hyphen. This forces browsers to use a different font, and while the non-breaking hyphen looks the same as normal hyphen in *that* font, there is no guarantee that it matches a normal hyphen from a different font.

Comment: I think Deb's answer is the best.

Comment: This sounds like the answer I need, though the below answer from Deb is what I originally solved the problem with. Until I saw xmojmr's comment, so now I am back to this answer, except the above does not work. Recognizing @Jukka K. Korpela's comment, I am now wondering if most web safe fonts such as Helvetica, and Arial, don't have this character, as I can't seem to get this to work with these fonts.

Comment: Not everyone can use Deb's answer due to restrictions on what content you can enter into a CMS.

Comment: Also, beware that since the non-breaking hyphen is indeed a different character from the regular dash, copy-pasting it into source code or other contexts where exact equality tends to matter, you can run into trouble. Similarly, using Ctrl-F in the browser and typing a regular dash won't find the non-breaking hyphens. (However, this could be the best answer depending on one's situation, so I upvoted both this and Deb's answer.)

Answer (score 324):

You could also wrap the relevant text with

```
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"></span>
```

Comment: Yes, this is a better answer than the accepted one imho. Thanks @Deb.

Comment: @CMH this does not help if you want to wrap whitespaces (blank places where user sees white space - nothing) but you don't want to split words with hyphens, e.g. word "e-mail". Accepted answer helps in this case

Comment: In that case you can just use span only around "e-mail".

Comment: @CMH, this is a good answer that also works, so I up-voted it.  However, I chose not to accept this answer because I asked for a character that wouldn't automatically break to the next line.  The fact that a "non-breaking hyphen" (`&#8209;`) ***might*** render slightly longer than a regular hyphen in certain browsers was trivial to me.

Comment: @Sparky One problem with using different characters is that it messes up search results. Trying to find "3-3/8" on the page will not find the nonbreaking hyphen.

Comment: While IMO this is the best answer for webpages, in html emails at least Outlook 2013 doesn't respect that CSS. The non-breaking hyphen solution from @CanSpice though works in Outlook.

Comment: Does not work on a modal/dialog (angular material) in Chrome. Created horizontal and vertical scroll bars.

Comment: I'm finding this causes the span element to break out of its container, instead of the whole thing inside the span wrapping to the next line. Behaviour seems to be: Wherever nowrap span starts, and no matter how long its content, just keep extending the line, regardless of parent container dimensions.

Comment: Of course this is not *always* a solution, but it worked for me to do this in the css to avoid annoying line breaks in my short `<code>` snippets: `code { white-space: nowrap; }`.

Comment: I agree that this is a far better solution than the accepted one, especially when used in `<code>` snippets that users can copy and paste.

Comment: Much more reasonable to searching through all my user's input and replacing their hyphens.

Answer (score 29):

IE8/9 render the non-breaking hyphen mentioned in CanSpice's answer longer than a typical hyphen. It is the length of an en-dash instead of a typical hyphen. This display difference was a deal breaker for me.

As I could not use the CSS answer specified by Deb I instead opted to use no break tags.

```
<nobr>e-mail</nobr>
```

In addition I found a specific scenario that caused IE8/9 to break on a hyphen.

- A string contains words separated by non-breaking spaces - `&nbsp;`
- Width is limited
- Contains a dash

IE renders it like this.

[image: Example of hyphen breaking in IE8/9]

The following code reproduces the problem pictured above. I had to use a meta tag to force rendering to IE9 as IE10 has fixed the issue. No fiddle because it does not support meta tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <style>
            body { padding: 20px; }
            div { width: 300px; border: 1px solid gray; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>      
            <p>If&nbsp;there&nbsp;is&nbsp;a&nbsp;-&nbsp;and&nbsp;words&nbsp;are&nbsp;separated&nbsp;by&nbsp;the&nbsp;whitespace&nbsp;code&nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&nbsp;then&nbsp;IE&nbsp;will&nbsp;wrap&nbsp;on&nbsp;the&nbsp;dash.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using `nobr` is the most cross-browser way and works independently of fonts and CSS. The `nobr` element is not defined in HTML specs, but this should be regarded as a formality only. But if you *must* write by HTML specs, then Deb’s answer, using CSS, is the best option.

Comment: I'm curious why you couldn't use the CSS solution.

Comment: @RyanAhearn - I'm using a third party tool that does not give me much control over html. It does not support inline tag declarations.

Comment: Instead of the '<nobr>' could you have not just used a span with a class and controlled it using the CSS?

Comment: @StephenESC - I couldn't use an alternate hyphen character (as I pointed out in my answer because it displays incorrectly). A span would not have prevented breaking on a hyphen either. You can take the code example I provided and try it for yourself. That is, if you can find IE8/9. Getting rarer to see it these days.

Comment: Note that the `nobr` tag is non-standard and might break any time. The MDN documentation does not recommend to use this tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nobr

Answer (score 26):

You can also do it "the joiner way" by inserting "[*`U+2060` Word Joiner*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2060/index.htm)".

If [`Accept-Charset`](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.2) permits, the unicode character itself can be **inserted directly** into the HTML output.

Otherwise, it can be done using entity encoding. E.g. to join the text `red-brown`, use:

```
red-&#x2060;brown
```

or (decimal equivalent):

```
red-&#8288;brown
```

. Another usable character is "*[`U+FEFF` Zero Width No-break Space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm)*"<sup><sup>[⁠ ⁠1 ]</sup></sup>:

```
red-&#xfeff;brown
```

and (decimal equivalent):

```
red-&#65279;brown
```

<sup>***[1]***: Note that while this method *still* works in major browsers like Chrome, it has [been deprecated since Unicode 3.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_joiner).</sup>

---

Comparison of "the joiner way" with "[*`U+2011` Non-breaking Hyphen*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2011/index.htm)":

- The word joiner can be used for all other characters, not just hyphens.
- When using the word joiner, most renderers will rasterize the text **identically**. On Chrome, FireFox, IE, and Opera, the rendering of normal hyphens, eg:

  > a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i-j-k-l-m-n-o-p-q-r-s-t-u-v-w-x-y-z

  is identical to the rendering of normal hyphens (with U+2060 Word Joiner), eg:

  > a-⁠b-⁠c-⁠d-⁠e-⁠f-⁠g-⁠h-⁠i-⁠j-⁠k-⁠l-⁠m-⁠n-⁠o-⁠p-⁠q-⁠r-⁠s-⁠t-⁠u-⁠v-⁠w-⁠x-⁠y-⁠z

  while the above two renders differ from the rendering of "*Non-breaking Hyphen*", eg:

  > a‑b‑c‑d‑e‑f‑g‑h‑i‑j‑k‑l‑m‑n‑o‑p‑q‑r‑s‑t‑u‑v‑w‑x‑y‑z

  . (The extent of the difference is browser-dependent and font-dependent. E.g. when using a font declaration of "`arial`", Firefox and IE11 show relatively huge variations, while Chrome and Opera show smaller variations.)

Comparison of "the joiner way" with `<span class=c1></span>` (CSS `.c1 {white-space:nowrap;}`) and `<nobr></nobr>`:

- The word joiner can be used for situations where usage of HTML tags is restricted, e.g. forms of websites and forums.
- On the [spectrum of presentation and content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_presentation_and_content), majority will consider the word joiner to be closer to content, when compared to tags.

---

<sup>• As tested on Windows 8.1 Core 64-bit using:

    • IE 11.0.9600.18205

    • Firefox 43.0.4

    • Chrome 48.0.2564.109 (Official Build) m (32-bit)

    • Opera 35.0.2066.92</sup>

Comment: It seems "U+FEFF Zero Width No-break Space" does not work correctly in IE11.

Comment: It seems "U+2060" does not work if "-" is followed by some unicode char: like this `bingo-&#8288;bongo`

Comment: Despite the constant negative press `&#xfeff;`

Comment: Awesome! I’m using a font in which, strangely, the nonbreaking hyphen displays as a space, so this was a life-safer, so to speak! Thank you! :)

Comment: Upvoted, as using Word Joiner also preserves Ctrl-f search, something that is broken if a non-breaking hyphen is used.

Search for "a-b-c" to observe this in the above post.

Answer (score 16):

Late to the party, but I think this is actually the most elegant. Use the WORD JOINER Unicode character [&#8288](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2060/index.htm); on either side of your hyphen, or em dash, or any character.

So, like so:

```
&#8288;—&#8288;
```

This will join the symbol on both ends to its neighbors (without adding a space) and prevent line breaking.

Comment: I was able to get this to work using ALT+0173 (soft hyphen) for some reason on Windows 10.

Comment: Wonderful solution! This is certainly the best way to ensure it will work without worrying about whether your font supports non-breaking characters.

Answer (score 4):

Following on from @den’s useful JSX solution, this worked for me:

```
<h2>{props.name.replace('-', '-\u2060')}</h2>
```

Comment: Also `replace('-', '\u2011')` which is equal to the non-breaking hyphen or `&#8209` (mentioned in the accepted answer) is a good option.

Comment: Nice answer. I would just add RegExp to replace all hyphens in text instead of the first one: `.replace(/-/gm, '-\u2060');`

Answer (score 1):

JSX solution example using [`word joiner`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_joiner) unicode character:

```js
<div>{`This is JSX-${'\u2060'}related example`}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be needing this for a JavaScript string...

Was able to make this thanks to [@CanSpice's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12362315/10415970) using the non-breaking hyphen. Make sure to not use hyphen break or auto alongside it.

```js
// Convert regular dash to non-breaking dash in string
function convertToNonBreakingDashes(inputString) {
  return inputString.replace(/-/g, '\u2011');
}
```