# Dash that prevents line-break between both words

Tags: html

Is there any way to have a dash ( - ) that wont break the word if it's ending a line? (Just like `&nbsp;` prevents a line break between two words)

The problem that I currently have is a blog post (dynamic) that has the word X-Ray in it. Sadly, it falls on the end of a line so I get

```
Lorem ipsum dolor si amet X-
Ray
```

I would like to prevent that, and get a result like this

```
Lorem ipsum dolor si amet
X-Ray
```

I can't just `<br />` everything, because depending on where you are on the website, it won't be stuck in that position everywhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No line-break after a hyphen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691569/no-line-break-after-a-hyphen)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a non-breaking hyphen, `&#8209;`

Info at http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2011/index.htm

Answer (score 7):

You can use the *[Unicode Character 'NON-BREAKING HYPHEN' (U+2011)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2011/index.htm)*.

```
HTML Entity (decimal)   &#8209;
HTML Entity (hex)   &#x2011;
How to type in Microsoft Windows    Alt +2011
UTF-8 (hex) 0xE2 0x80 0x91 (e28091)
UTF-8 (binary)  11100010:10000000:10010001
UTF-16 (hex)    0x2011 (2011)
UTF-16 (decimal)    8,209
UTF-32 (hex)    0x00002011 (2011)
UTF-32 (decimal)    8,209
C/C++/Java source code  "\u2011"
Python source code  u"\u2011"
```

Answer (score 1):

The way that works most widely is `<nobr>X-ray</nobr>`. Despite not being part of any HTML spec, the `nobr` tag works well.

Nowadays, using the non-breaking hyphen U+2011 (suggested in other answers; you can also enter it directly, if you know how to do that in your editor and you are using UTF-8) works almost as widely. There are risks, however. [Support to U+2011](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2011/fontsupport.htm) is not universal in fonts. This means that unless you take special measures to use a font that contains it, or to use suitable backup fonts, it is quite possible that the non-breaking hyphen looks different from the normal hyphen (which is mostly the “Ascii hyphen” on web pages).

This means that foo-bar and foo‑bar (with non-breaking hyphen) may look different, since they come from different fonts. It might take a trained eye or a typographer to see the difference, but in some font combinations, the difference is clearly observable.

Using `nobr`, you don’t have this problem, since the same character is used. The same applies to using `<span style="white-space: nowrap">X-ray</span>`, but it’s a bit clumsier and a little bit less reliable (does not work when CSS is disabled).

Comment: The site being a wordpress, it would be pretty hard to implement that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What is difficult in switching to HTML mode and adding tags?

Comment: I'm great at HTML. My client/user sucks at it.

Answer (score -1):

[This site](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) Will provide you with more information than you'll ever need.

```
&#8211;
```

Is what you're after though.

Comment: No, it is the en dash, and there is no guarantee that it prevents line breaks.