# how to represent dash and hypen in html and use it in java code

Tags: html

I used `&#045;` to reperesnt hypen it is giving me dash but  I need hypen can anybody let me know how to do this.

Comment: The title says “java code”, but the question is tagged with “html” only. Which one is it about?

Comment: I think the accepted answer in this question might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691569/no-line-break-after-a-hyphen

Comment: What do you mean by “dash” and “hypen”? The reference `&#045;` denotes HYPHEN-MINUS, an Ascii character commonly called “hyphen”, whereas “dash” normally means EN DASH (–) or EM DASH (—). So which character do you want? (Describing the context and purpose might help to guess what is really needed.)

Answer (score 0):

The hyphen character is the Unicode character U+2010, so you use `&#8208;` to put it in the HTML code.

Comparison between hyphen, hyphen-minus (ASCII dash) and minus:

Go‐getter (`&#8208;`)
Go-getter (`-` / `&#45;`)
Go−getter (`#8722;`)