# How to manage text breaks in span using js, css or anything else

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, text

The title might be a little confusing, but didn't know how to name it correctly. Basically I have a text like this:

```
content3 (-content1) content4 (-content2)
```

which I display in a span element. The element has a varied widths and in some case text above needs to be broken into two lines. Unfortunately it often brakes on '-' symbol which make it look like this:

```
content3 (-content1) content4 (-
content2)
```

Is there any way I could prevent it from happening. Would be happy with this format:

```
content3 (-content1) content4 
(-content2)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No line-break after a hyphen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691569/no-line-break-after-a-hyphen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enclose your content in a `span`, you can use `white-space:nowrap;` to make the content drop down.

HTML

```
<div class="sup" id="pr">
    <strong>
        <span class="content">content3</span>
        <span class="content">(-content1)</span>
        <span class="content">content4 </span> 
        <span class="content">(-content2)</span>
    </strong>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.sup {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
#pr {
    width:100%;
}
.content {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/945Df/116/)

Answer (score 0):

You can always go around this by using a non-breaking hyphen `&#8209;`.
I'm not sure if this is the ideal solution and it isn't elegant but it will solve your problem and it is simple.