# Non-breaking dash html

Tags: css, html

I know that there is a non breaking whitespace - `&nbsp;`. Is there a non-breaking dash (`-`) I can use so that my word doesn't wrap (break) at that location. Also can someone point me to a list with characters that are considered with priority when breaking a sentence ( like a whitespace). Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `&#8209;` instead of `-`, see the following example:

```css
.box {
  border:1px solid #000;
  width:40px;
  word-wrap:normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  This is a test&#8209;case / test-case
</div>
```

Comment: Good attempt, but if a question is marked as duplicate is better following mark duplicated, instead of copy the answer and put it here. I upvote because is correct, but that's a duplicated question

Comment: It's not a duplicate because a hyphen is different from a dash. For anyone else happening across this page looking for a non-breaking _dash_, try here: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/124347/non-breaking-en-dash/

Comment: the code snippet shows as either an empty box or a question mark for me. I'm running chrome latest on m1 macbook pro.

Comment: @Eriyu following that reasoning, this question also was not a duplicate.