# chrome wrap looooooooooong words with '-' in html source code

Tags: html, google-chrome, word-wrap

A long words with '-' may be wrapped in HTML source code in chrome. For example, I have a long word myfatherwasaself-taughtaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa....aaaaaaa.

In Chrome, the word will break at '-' in both source code and rendered html, but in Edge, the word is displayed correctly. This figure may be more clear.

Contrast Figure:

[image]

My Chrome version is 54.0.2840.59 and Edge version is 38.14393.0.0. Can somebody tell me why Chrome wrap word when encounter a '-'? Does Chrome process the '-' particularly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No line-break after a hyphen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691569/no-line-break-after-a-hyphen)

Comment: What defines "displayed correctly"? Specs probably don't say anything of this case so there is no "correctly", only "how I'd like to"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a non-breaking hypen: `&#8209;`

Similar concept to a non-breaking space: `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 0):

Or give the element a `white-space: nowrap;` CSS property.

```css
span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<span>myfatherwasaself-taughtaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa....aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
```