# Avoid line-breaks after hyphen in R Shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny, dt, flexdashboard

It seems that Shiny automatically introduces a line-break after hyphen (`-`) characters, at least when used together with datatables (see example below). I guess this is related to [a similar problem in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691569/no-line-break-after-a-hyphen), and probably happens when the document is rendered into HTML, but here replacing the hyphen by a "non-breaking" version (`&#8209;`) won't work, neither does replacing the hyphen by the long version (`—`).

Here is an example code reproducing this problem, where I create a variable with a minus sign in its name, and want to show its name (including the minus sign) in the table header. As you can see, a line-break after `-` appears.

````
---
title: "Example"
runtime: shiny
theme: simplex
vertical_layout: fill
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
  orientation: rows
---

Explore
======================================================================

```{r echo = FALSE}
library("tidyverse")
library("shiny")
library("DT")
```

```{r echo = FALSE}
createDataTable <- function (data) {

  data %>%  

    DT::datatable(
      extensions = c('Buttons','Scroller'),
      rownames=FALSE,
      options = list(
        paging = TRUE,
        pageLength = nrow(data),
        searching = TRUE,
        fixedColumns = TRUE,
        autoWidth = FALSE,
        ordering = TRUE,
        scroller = TRUE,
        scrollX = '400px',
        scrollY = '300px',
        dom = 'Bfrtip',
        buttons = list(
          'copy',
          list(
            extend='collection',
            buttons = list (
              list(extend='csv', filename='catalog'),
              list(extend='excel', filename='catalog'),
              list(extend='pdf', filename='catalog')
            ),
            text='Download'),
          'print'
        )
      )
    )
}
```

```{r echo = FALSE}
DT::renderDataTable(
  server=FALSE, {
  mtcars %>% dplyr::mutate(`-mpg` = -mpg, a_longer_name_for_mpg = mpg) %>% createDataTable()
})

```
````

Does anybody know how to avoid this behavior without changing the `DT` functions used, and without refusing to include the hyphen in the column header?

**EDIT**

It seems that if the page is view in full screen mode, there is no page-break. But it has nothing to do with the length of the variable name (the code is updated also to create a new variable with a longer name). So there should be a way to avoid this behavior, independently of the screen size.

This is my `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Arch Linux

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/libblas.so.3.8.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3.8.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=es_ES.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=es_ES.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=es_ES.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=es_ES.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.6.0        rsconnect_0.8.13      htmltools_0.3.6       tools_3.6.0           flexdashboard_0.5.1.1
 [6] yaml_2.2.0            Rcpp_1.0.1            rmarkdown_1.13        knitr_1.23            jsonlite_1.6         
[11] xfun_0.7              digest_0.6.19         evaluate_0.13
```

Comment: could you add the packages and/or the environment (markdown...) required please ? I'm not very familiar with this sort of code

Comment: I have edited the post with some libraries that could be missing, as well as with the result of `sessionInfo()`

Comment: well that's strange because when I set the window in full screen, there is no line-break (I'm using windows 10), have you tried to open it in browser ?

Comment: Well, you are right, it seems that this *fixes* the problem, even when the size is reduced after using the full screen view. However, still cannot understand why this line-break. Note that if a new variable is added with a longer name, the line-break has nothing to do with it, but with the hyphen. I edit the question to show this.

Comment: I don't know yet how to fix it, but you should notice that it is not due to the hyphen in particular : if you replace -mpg by new_mpg for example, the problem is the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable the wrapping by using the class `nowrap`:

```
DT::datatable(
  class = "display nowrap",
  extensions = c('Buttons','Scroller'),
  ......
```

Comment: Yes! this works as expected. Interesting option calling CSS classes. Thank you!