# (CSS Only) Prevent word break in line jump, when the word have a "-"

Tags: html, css

He guys, can anyone tell me if there is a solution for words breaking "-", i dont want to cut words with "-", so it needs to get in the next line the entire word.

i have tried `white-space: pre-wrap;` but it does not work.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at using the non breaking hyphen? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7691604/73226

Comment: @MartinSmith i dont undertand how to use it. it does not look like is working.

Comment: @MartinSmith never mind, investigating your suggesttion i found the solution, i used non-breaking hyphen &#8209; and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using the non-breaking hyphen `&#8209;`, worked for me.